# Stacked Bar Chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

I would like to have a stacked bar-chart. I succesfully created my dataframe using lubridate, however as I can just specify x and y values I do not know how to 'put in' my data values.

The dataframe is looking like so:

```
Date           Feature1    Feature2    Feature3
2020-01-01     72          0           0
2020-02-01     90          21          5
2020-03-01     112         28          2
2020-04-01     140         36          0
...
```

The date should be on the x-axis and each row represents one bar in the bar chart (the height of the bar is the sum of `Feature1`+`Feature2`+`Feature3`

The only thing I get is this:

```
ggplot(dataset_monthly, aes(x = dataset_monthly$Date, y =dataset_monthly$????)) + 
+   geom_bar(stat = "stack")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format first

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dataset_monthly %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = 'Feature') %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = Feature)) +
         geom_col()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
dataset_monthly <- structure(list(Date = 
  structure(c(18262, 18293, 18322, 18353), class = "Date"), 
    Feature1 = c(72L, 90L, 112L, 140L), Feature2 = c(0L, 21L, 
    28L, 36L), Feature3 = c(0L, 5L, 2L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: great this did the job :) In the barchart for example I just want to show feature1 and feature2, feature 3 should be shown using a line. Is there some way excluding the values with `feature3`from the geom_col()?

Comment: @SRel Probably `dataset_monthly %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(Date, Feature3), names_to = 'Feature')  %>% ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = Feature)) +
         geom_col() + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Feature3))`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified using `geom_bar`. thanks to akrun!

```
library(tidyverse)
# Bring data in longformat -> same code as akruns!
df <- dataset_monthly %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = 'Feature') 


ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=value, fill=Feature, label = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.8)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]